# express.js emojis are not displayed

Tags: express, webserver, send

Im currently trying to develope a express webserver. The server sends a site with emojis, but the emojis are just shown as ??. Code:

`send = send + "<div id='Website'> <a href='"+webseite+"'>Website</a></div>"`

And it looks like this:

```
?? Website
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you test your application using the same browser that you use to post this question? I'm asking because I've copied your code and I'm seeing emoji in responses from Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you you NodeJS with express, you can use :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-emoji

Il will stringify your emoji

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but it might help others you can set charset to UTF-8 for example:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
  res.end("  ");
});
```